# Use wget to mirror a site to a static site

Tags: 6, blocks, navigation

I'm trying to use the following command to mirror a Drupal 6 site which needs to be archived as a static site. Unfortunately, I've only been able to find a [static generator for Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/project/static), not 6. I'm having issues because it seems that

1. By logging in as different roles, the wget command will pull down completely different directory structures. This is not unanticipated, but in some cases as an administrator there is quite a lot of content missing which is pulled down with accounts that have lesser permissions.
2. There are links on the main page in separate blocks whose directory and pages do not get pulled down in the file directory structure by logging in with any role, including administrator.

So far I've successfully been able to mirror the site (with the above limitations), but I'm not sure if the command is actually mirroring the entire site as I need it to do. Here is the code I am using for `wget`:

```
wget --mirror -w 2 -p --convert-links --load-cookies cookies.txt -e robots=off https://url.org/user
```

where the cookies file is created like this:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'name=MY_USERNAME&pass=MY_PASSWORD&form_build_id=FORM_ID&form_id=user_login&op=Log+in' https://url.org/user
```

I am very new to Drupal, so am not sure how roles and permissions, or the structure of the content might affect a `wget mirror` operation. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why the downvote? Most information regarding archiving or creating static sites from Drupal are for Drupal 7. I think this is a completely legitimate question and I've explained what I tried, and what the issues are.

Comment: Not the down voter, but I'll take a guess. 1. There's not much an explicit question to answer (DA is Q&A format, not a forum). 2. The post is incidentally about Drupal; the question seems to be, "how can I login to my CMS via `wget` to so I can completely mirror a static version of my site?"

Comment: Ok, I understand what you're saying about the discussion. There isn't really another place to ask this aside from Drupal.org. I began posting on stack overflow, but once I tagged "Drupal" it suggested that I post my query here. I think I make it pretty clear that I know how to log in to my CMS via `wget`, but it appears that with different permissions come different directory structures and content files. I was hoping for some help in understanding why that might be happening, and how Drupal's setup might prevent a `wget mirror` from obtaining certain aspects of a site.

Comment: You're encouraged to answer your own questions. You can take your the solution you added, write it as an answer, and mark it with the checkmark. This helps curious future readers know that it helped you solve the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks Shawn. Didn't know if that was appropriate or not. I'll do it though now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue had to do with the fact that a "Logout" block was in the header of the main site. As a result, when wget went to pull things down, it would actually go to the logout link, and thus the rest of the files would either display a login screen or wouldn't be downloaded. By disabling the logout block OR adding --reject logout to my wget command, it seems to have fixed the issue and now the full directory structure is being downloaded. The command I ended up using was:

```
wget --mirror -w 2 -p --convert-links --load-cookies cookies.txt -e robots=off --reject logout https://url.org/user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -mnH -k --html-extension https://example.com
```

I'm not setting any cookies, but this is what I usually run to mirror a website and it works well. You can sub the last portion if you don't want html extensions

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll give that a shot. The cookies are really important in my case, and I almost wonder if that is the issue since it seems to influence which files and directories are mirrored with `wget`.

Comment: Could you run the site locally or on another server, change permissions and then mirror that?